# Positive definite matrix after taking out the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

inverse of a positive definite matrix = inverse(A)

inverse(**A**)=[1/(determinant of **A**)]***B**
Question: is **B** still a positive definite matrix?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

The inverse of a positive-definite matrix is positive definite, and the determinant of a positive-definite matrix is positive (since the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, all of which are positive). So, $B$ must also be positive definite.

Comment: thanks cmk.If A=[a,b;c,d], is B=[d,-c;-b,a] also positive definite?

Comment: @Art1 note that they have the same eigenvalues.